# How to achieve this Map<String, List<>> structure and send POST request with JSON data using Volley

Tags: android, hashmap, gson, android-volley

I have data like below:

```
{
    "date": "2022-11-15",
    "number": "2222",
    "user": "Faisal",
    "report_note": "Test",
    "detail": [{
            "desc": "",
            "usable": 0,
            "condition": "GOOD",
            "numbering": "CRT-0002",
            "numbering_id": "2",
            "code": "F"
        },
        {
            "desc": "",
            "usable": 0,
            "condition": "GOOD",
            "numbering": "CRT-0001",
            "numbering_id": "1",
            "code": "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to send a new JsonObjectRequest request:

- I want to receive JSON data (response from server): OK
- I want to send JSON formatted data with this request to the server

```
private void createPackagingReturn() {
    String url = "some/url";
    
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("date", date);
    params.put("number", number);
    params.put("user", name);
    params.put("report_note", report);
    params.put("detail", json);
    
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response :" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    title = "Information";
                    message = response.toString();
                    alertMessageError(title,message);
                    System.out.println(response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        String status = jObj.getString("status");

                        if (status.equals("ok"))
                        {
                            //String message = jObj.getString("message");
                            title = "Success";
                            message = "ok";                         
                            alertMessage(title,message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            title = "Error";
                            message = "error";
                            //alertMessageError(title,message);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }){
        
        @Override
        public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            String bearer = "bearer ".concat(jwt);
            Map<String,String> headersSys = super.getHeaders();
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headersSys.remove("Authorization");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", bearer);
            headers.putAll(headersSys);
            return headers;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

P.S. I use GSON library in my project too. Please help?

I would like to send post a new JsonObjectRequest request with Json data

Comment: why don't you use retrofit library. It works well with Gson

Comment: any example to use retrofit library in my case?